# Linking one SVN repository to multiple Trac repository

Tags: svn, trac

I am trying to have the following set up.

Assume that my customer has two different project developments in one SVN repository, project A and project B.  Project A and project B are also sharing the same Trac repository.  My customer is asking me to do the following:

•Both Project A and B are going to share the same SVN repository.

•Project A and B need to have separate Trac repositories.

•When there is a commit on the project A part of the SVN repository, the referenced ticket on the Trac repository A needs to be updated.

•When there is a commit on the project B part of the SVN repository, the referenced ticket on the Trac repository B needs to be updated.

I looked at http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki and I didn’t find anything about one SVN repository for multiple Trac repositories.  I was wondering if this capability exists? If yes, then could you provide the link so I can read and learn?

Thank you for considering my request.

Answer (score 0):

Better use just one Trac environment (means Trac instance), configure the use of two SVN repos there. Install [SimpleMultiProjectPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SimpleMultiProjectPlugin) to have multiple user-projects in a single Trac. You will have one unique ticket system where the name of the user-project is just another ticket field you should fill in. SVN commits refer to any tickets, it's up to the user to address the right ticket of a certain user-project. The plugin adds functionality to filter and sort tickets by user-projects (on Trac's timeline and roadmap pages).

Maybe install [Bitnami Trac Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/trac/installer) to get a consistent all-in-one package of Apache+SVN+Trac+Python saving many hours of install hell.